# Dynamics Send Port - BizTalk

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk

Saludos,

I'm trying to build a dynamic send port inside an orchestration, but I'm the following error

> "The property "OutboundTransportLocation" has a value with length
>   greater than 256 characters"

```
MessageOut = MessageIn;
jsonMessage = {"id":0,"original":"1","tipoId":"610","comments":"BizTalk","privadoNotes":null,"PriodidadyValue":null,"cityId":"1","streetNum":null,"streetId":"0","crossStreetId":"0","latitude":"0","longitude":"0"}
InitialUri = System.String.Format("http://ThisIsaURLTheRealOneAndBig.com/someplace/api/v1/requests/add/?key=5dd5d45d4sdd54dds5s54s5s45s4s5s4s545s4swws&request={0}", jsonMessage);
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Orchestration Debug", System.String.Format("The Value = {0}", InitialUri));
MessageOut(WCF.BindingType)="WsHttpBinding";
DynamicsTOSend(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = InitialUri; //this URI Finally is bigger than 256
DynamicsTOsend(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "HTTP";
```

please any idea?

Comment: Never mind, it can be worked using WCF-WebHttp as a transport type in biztalk 2013.
http://www.codit.eu/blog/2014/06/24/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-biztalk-2013-r2-wcf-webhttp-adapter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, it can be worked using WCF-WebHttp as a transport type in Biztalk 2013.

http://www.codit.eu/blog/2014/06/24/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-biztalk-2013-r2-wcf-webhttp-adapter/

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the limit on promoted properties of 256 characters